# would(=insistence)

Tags: meaning-in-context, auxiliary-verbs

**He *would* leave the house in a muddle.**

**He insisted on leaving the house in a muddle.**

What's the difference between the former sentence and the latter sentence?

(Here, *would* of the first sentence means the speaker's insistence.)

Comment: The first sentence with **would**, absent other context, doesn't imply the involvement of any other person; it speaks only of his intention, whereas "insisted" implies the involvement of someone else who may have had a different opinion or desire than he did.

Comment: **Insisted on** rather implies that he did it on purpose; **he would do it** here implies annoyance  that he habitually did so, probably just because he was an untidy person.

Comment: Insisted - crazy. would - lazy.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences could mean similar, but only from a third-party perspective and in their opinion.

Saying "*he would leave*...." can mean *it was his habit to leave in this fashion*. It can also imply 'insist', but only if strong emphasis is put on the spoken word 'would' (perhaps that is what your italics implied, unless you were just highlighting the word for the purpose of the question).

This use of "insist" does not literally mean that the person demanded he be allowed to do something - it commonly means that *they would not be told otherwise*, or that they refused to acknowledge they were disorganised.

'A muddle' means a disordered, confused state, or a mess. I don't think anyone is leaving the house at the protest of their family saying "*no, no - I really must insist that I leave the house in this disordered mess*". While some people surely are disorganised, that is my opinion. In the opinion of the muddled individual, they might be just fine. It really means a defiance of anything to the contrary.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful reply.

Comment: So, in BrE, does saying that someone  "insisted on leaving the room a mess" imply that they have been asked to be neater but are being  recalcitrant, refusing to do so? Or only that they are inveterate slobs?