Why is "have cooked" used instead of "cook" or "cooked" in this sentence?
I came across the following sentence:

"Why would they have cooked their food at all?"

The context is a discussion about the behavior of people in ancient times.
I'm curious why "have cooked" is used here instead of:

"Why would they cook their food at all?" (using the bare infinitive "cook")
or
"Why did they cook their food at all?" (using the simple past tense "cooked")

Could someone please explain the grammatical reason for using "have cooked" in this case and how it differs in meaning from the other two options?

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344450/would-insistence/351355#351355
